# Mdx Query Show Year Level Data for all years except This Year

Tags: mdx

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {[Measures].[AMOUNTCUR]} ON 0
 ,NON EMPTY 
    {
      NULL : [PRX_UE_DATE].[Calender].[Year].&[2015]
     ,[PRX_UE_DATE].[Calender].[Year].&[2017]
     ,Descendants
      (
        [PRX_UE_DATE].[Calender].[Year].&[2016]
       ,[PRX_UE_DATE].[Calender].[Month]
      )
    } ON 1
FROM [PRX_SalesDataModel];
```

I have a query like above. It's working It returns 2016 on month based others years are year based.

Now I have to add  more dimensions on this mdx but when i try it to like

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {[Measures].[AMOUNTCUR]} ON 0
 ,NON EMPTY 
    {
      NULL : [PRX_UE_DATE].[Calender].[Year].&[2015]
     ,[PRX_UE_DATE].[Calender].[Year].&[2017]
     ,
        Descendants
        (
          [PRX_UE_DATE].[Calender].[Year].&[2016]
         ,[PRX_UE_DATE].[Calender].[Month]
        )
      * 
        [PRX UE CLIENT].[SEGMENTID].ALLMEMBERS
    } ON 1
FROM [PRX_SalesDataModel];
```

I get error Members, tuples or sets must use the same hierarchies in the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to keep all the date dimension stuff in set braces `{...}`:

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {[Measures].[AMOUNTCUR]} ON 0
 ,NON EMPTY 
    {
      NULL : [PRX_UE_DATE].[Calender].[Year].&[2015]
     ,[PRX_UE_DATE].[Calender].[Year].&[2017]
     ,
        Descendants
        (
          [PRX_UE_DATE].[Calender].[Year].&[2016]
         ,[PRX_UE_DATE].[Calender].[Month]
        ) 
     }
     * [PRX UE CLIENT].[SEGMENTID].ALLMEMBERS
     ON 1
FROM [PRX_SalesDataModel];
```

You could even make it maybe more readable by moving the date stuff into a named set via a WITH clause:

```
WITH SET [DatesSet] AS
    {
      NULL : [PRX_UE_DATE].[Calender].[Year].&[2015]
     ,[PRX_UE_DATE].[Calender].[Year].&[2017]
     ,
        Descendants
        (
          [PRX_UE_DATE].[Calender].[Year].&[2016]
         ,[PRX_UE_DATE].[Calender].[Month]
        ) 
     }
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {[Measures].[AMOUNTCUR]} ON 0
 ,NON EMPTY 
    [DatesSet]
     * [PRX UE CLIENT].[SEGMENTID].ALLMEMBERS
     ON 1
FROM [PRX_SalesDataModel];
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Now, I understand my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You've got your answer from @whytheq on why the error cropped up. There is just one part which I felt is not handled yet. You are building the set of years by hand. Instead of that, it can be made dynamic like below -

```
with set AllYearsExceptCurrent as
filter(
       [PRX_UE_DATE].[Calender].[Year].members as yr,
       yr.current.item(0).member_value <> Format(Now(), "yyyy")
      )
```

Comment: (upped) I like that - might also be a alternative nice solution using `subset` ?

Comment: Hmm...that's one one function I have not used much, but hell yeah, it can also be used..yesterday, came across the most weird MDX I have ever seen. You too take a look and tell me if it isn't beautiful :) - http://blog.gbrueckl.at/cube-functions/

Comment: using the function `axis()` is another level